# How to get the count of matching rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

[click the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj9Zo.png)
How to get matched records count if(t1.column1=t2.column) or if(t2.column=null)then it should be count.if (t1.column!=t2.column) it should not be counted
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj9Zo.png)

Comment: So your table1 has company Germany and location BMW? Is that right?

Comment: yes,so it should not be counted as matched row

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.COMAPNY= table2.COMPANY AND table1.LOCATION= table2.LOCATION` something like this? 
This,assuming you meant to put BMW in company in table one in your picture, will count how many matches between the tables where location and company match.

Comment: no ,because of column value interchanged that is also should not comes in count